# MySql - Selecting all records with the same field when one row matches the result

Tags: mysql, select

I have made a fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1f15

I Have this table

```
id |  sid  | product
---------------------
1  |  ABC  |   1
2  |  ABC  |   2
3  |  ABC  |   3
4  |  BCD  |   1
5  |  BCD  |   2
6  |  XYZ  |   2
7  |  XYZ  |   3
```

What i want is to get all SID's if one SID have the product = 3
The result i was looking is:

```
id |  sid  | product
---------------------
1  |  ABC  |   1
2  |  ABC  |   2
3  |  ABC  |   3
6  |  XYZ  |   2
7  |  XYZ  |   3
```

Im completely stuck, please help! Thanks

Comment: you have got so many answers. Please accept one that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use self-join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM sp_test t1
JOIN sp_test t2
ON t1.sid = t2.sid AND t2.product = '3';
```

Or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sp_test t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT  1 FROM sp_test t2 WHERE t1.sid = t2.sid AND t2.product = '3'
);
```

#### SQLFiddle Demo

Answer (score 2):

Use simple left join as below:

```
select sp1.* from sp_test sp1 left join sp_test sp2 on sp1.sid=sp2.sid
where sp2.product=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple nested query.

```
SELECT * FROM sp_test
WHERE sid IN (SELECT sid FROM sp_test WHERE product = 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation:

```
select 
  id, sid, product
from 
  sp_test x
where 
  exists (
    select 
      1
    from 
      sp_test y
    where 
      y.product = '3' 
      and x.sid = y.sid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.sid, t1.product
FROM sp_test t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sid
    FROM sp_test
    GROUP BY sid
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN product = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.sid = t2.sid
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: @Drew Very funny, also your browser had very dark, Goth-like, colors.

Comment: Yeah it saves your [eyes](http://i.imgur.com/9pNGx1j.jpg) when you stare at this screen so much. A userscript some of us use that works with Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey. Want it?

Comment: Yeah sure feel free to Skype me a link ;-)

Comment: I stuck it here on a github repository if anyone wants it: [link](https://github.com/drewpierce/TMUserScripts)